# Is it possible to link a file(exe) that within the resource folder to my compiled windows form program?

Tags: c#

I have a program that i made in visual studio,i want my new program to extract it and use it,i don't want to give a whole installation, i want to give away only my executable file.
The thing is that i don't know how to link the my older exe file into my new program without installation.

example:
Lets say i made Prog.exe, now at my new project which named Prog2 there is resource folder which contains Prog.exe.
I want that Prog.exe will be "inside" of my program, that it will make my Prog2 executable to run this program when the exe is given alone.

Edit:
I Have attempted taking the "Prog.exe" using the code
`Properties.Resource.Prog`
then extracting it to desktop which works great but that's not my problem, my problem is how can i "keep" prog.exe to my program without installation, i mean when i wan to give my program to other computer i want to give only my "Prog2.exe" and not my prog2.exe with addition ONLY Prog2.exe.
i used filestearm to extract the file from resource onto desktop but if without my resource folder the file created is 0 kb means broken..
the compiled program is a windows service that will be installed in my new program, in order to install it i need the exe file extracted.

Edit2:
What i mean is when u compile my program it isn't compiling with the resource folder right?
so how am i adding a file that would be "inside" of my compiled exe, that if i take this file to other computer it will work and will succeed running perfectly

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to use when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: Start by recompiling your original code as a dll. That should give you more flexibility in terms of reusing it.

Comment: I'm guessing that the file is 0KB because you forgot to `Flush` the stream. I have updated my answer to include that instruction.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment by gunr2171, there are many possible ways to do this. This is how I would go about it:

Add a Files resource to your program that is the other EXE, I'll call it `Prog2` like you did.  Then, use the following code to write it to disk and run it:

```
FileStream exe = new FileStream("Prog2.exe", IO.FileMode.Create);
exe.Write(Properties.Resources.Prog2, 0, Properties.Resources.Prog2.Length);
exe.Flush();
exe.Dispose();
Process.Start("Prog2.exe");
```

Keep in mind that the write could fail if you're in a read-only environment, or the process start could be blocked. Wrap it in a `try` block and be prepared to handle such issues. If you  need to wait for the other program to finish before continuing, I'd suggest creating a "lock" file that the other program deletes when it finishes and send the main program into a loop until that file is gone (of course with a time-out mechanism).